# What's the purpose of the Dark Matter counter?

Tags: solar-2

Playing in Dark Matter mode, a counter appears which seems to count how many Dark Matter asteroids (as a planet) or planets (as a star) I have absorbed. This also seems to determine the coloring, since the blue star in the screenshot only has a count of 11 (while it is still surrounded by that Dark Matter "field" since I created it from a Dark Matter planet):

[image: screenshot]

But what is the actual importance of this? Has this for example any influence on the creation of a Black Hole when colliding with usual matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no purpose! It was a holdover from an earlier version of the game. Here is the developer's answer to this question copied from [this steam forum](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2035690):

> It's sort of a relic of the 'discrete units of mass' system I used to
>   have, but when I changed that to fractional values the discrete dark
>   matter units don't really make sense anymore. So now it just
>   represents how many dark matter asteroids that has been absorbed. It
>   never really ended up as a big part of the game, so I didn't see the
>   need to fix it.